# Terminal velocity of a metal sphere in water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity, projectile, drag, viscosity

I am trying to figure out the terminal velocity of a metal ball dropped into water or oil.
After searching a bit on the internet, I came to the conclusion that I needed to use Stokes' Law and Archimedes principle.
$$6 π r \eta v+ρ g V$$
And since I am trying to find the terminal velocity I solve for $v$

$$v=\frac{-ρ g V+m g} {6 π r n}$$

Cool, I insert my values for oil first. Rapeseed oil specifically.
$ρ=800 kg/m^3$
$\eta=0.0372 Pa/s$

And the parameters of the metal ball
$r=0.0125m$
$m=0.027kg$
$g=9.82m/s^2$
$V=8.181*10^{-6}$

The output is $22.9m/s$ which at least sounds correct.

Although when I use the same formula for water, where the density is higher but viscosity lower I get an absurd result.
The difference between water and oil is only that now:
$ρ=997 kg/m^3$
$\eta=0.001 Pa/s$

$$v=\frac{-997kg/m^3\cdot9.82m/s^2\cdot (8.181\times10^{-6}))+0.027kg\cdot9.82m/s^2} {6\cdotπ\cdot0.0125m\cdot0.001}=785m/s $$
Which I'm pretty certain isn't correct.

After spending countless hours searching I stumbled upon Reynolds number. Which is supposed to tell me whether the flow is laminar or turbulent. And if Stokes' law is applicable.
By using: $$Re=\frac{ρ D v}{\eta}$$

I get $Re=12321$ for oil, and $Re=1.957*10^7$ for water. And according to the Reynolds Number thresholds that I found, the flow is turbulent in both cases, and Stokes' Law isn't applicable. I've spent many hours trying to figure out how to calculate the terminal velocity in a turbulent flow, but without success.

**So my question is, how to calculate the terminal velocity of a sphere, in a turbulent flow, in water?**

I'm only on my first year of physics in ''gymnasium'' in Denmark (equivalent of high school I believe), so please forgive me if I've used any wrong terminology.

Comment: I made the same mistake in my first physics tutorial at university, much to the amusement of the tutor. For turbulent flow see [quadratic drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation).

Comment: The units of viscosity are Pa-sec, not Pa/sec